# Custom find and count record by model fields in Cakephp

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

What's up guys,

I'm trying to search into my database, but Cakephp does not recognize my 'conditions', let's face it.

I need to list all Schedules grouped by Procedure.name and that are Schedule.comp mm/yyyy. I'm trying this way;

```
public function teste() {
    $this->layout = "ajax";
    $procedures = $this->Procedure->Schedule->find('all', 
        array(
            'group' => array('Procedure.name'),
            'Schedule.conditions' => array('Schedule.comp' => '12/2016'),
        ));
    $this->set(compact('procedures')); 
}
```

But, cake returns all Schedules, even those who have not Schedule bound

My model relations is:

Schedule belongsTo Procedure
Procedure hasMany Schedule

Best rewards,

Comment: If you need **all** schedules where `comp = xyz`, grouped by the procedure name, how would you expect this to work with the kind of SQL level grouping that you are showing here? Doing so would result in only one schedule per group being returned. You may want to elaborate on how exactly you want the results and the query to look like, and what they currently look like.

Comment: Can you give us more informations, Relations between models and tables shema would help

Answer (score 0):

Date should be in YYYY-mm-dd format.

```
$date = '2016-05'; 
public function teste() {
    $this->layout = "ajax";
    $procedures = $this->Procedure->Schedule->find('all', 
        array(
            'group' => array('Procedure.name'),
            'conditions' => array('Schedule.comp' => '12/2016'),
        ));
    $this->set(compact('procedures')); 
}
```

Comment: Comp is string, not date;

Comment: Thanks for your replay, but Schedule.Comp is varchar(7), not date ou datetime;

Comment: Can you check now?

Comment: Yes, I testing this way before, but don't work, Cakephp returns all Procedures. ;/